# How to filter tags to be included/excluded in a clocktable

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'd like to set up a clocktable where I can specify what tags to include and exclude.

I've tried the below. I've tried with and without double quotes, using + and &, and using :match as well as :tags, nothing seems to work. From [the manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/The-clock-table.html) it seems that :match should do exactly what I want, but it just includes everything no matter what I do.

```
#+TAGS: { billable(a) notes(o) travel(b) }
#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope file :tags +"billable"+"notes"-"travel"
#+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2019-09-20 Fri 21:49]
| Headline     | Time   |
|--------------+--------|
| *Total time* | *1:00* |
|--------------+--------|
| Session      | 1:00   |
#+END:
* Session   :billable:
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2019-09-19 Thu 17:30]--[2019-09-19 Thu 18:30] =>  1:00
:END:
* Notes    :notes:
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2019-09-19 Thu 18:30]--[2019-09-19 Thu 18:45] =>  0:15
:END:
* Travel   :travel:
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2019-09-19 Thu 18:45]--[2019-09-19 Thu 18:55] =>  0:10
:END:
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the correct syntax is to have all tags within a single double quote.

```
:tags "billable|notes-travel"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since org-mode version 9.2, the `:tags` argument adds a column with tags when set to `t`. The argument `:match` has the old functionality that matches specific tags.

From the [changelog](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-release-notes.html#org99be80c),

> The :match (renamed from :tags) option allows to limit clock entries to those matching a todo-tags matcher.

> The old :tags option can be set to t to display a headline's tags in a dedicated column.